# when i want to create a new ActinPerformed its code is writting inside an other ActinPerformed

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

here is my problem when i click right button and i want to add my actioPerformed i see that is the code os inside an old actionperformed

```
private void jButton8ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  
        Connection cx ;
        PreparedStatement psd ;
        ResultSet stt=null ;
        String url="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Dacia";
        String usr="daciasys" ;
        String pswd="daciasys" ;

    if(jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().equals("tous")) {   

     try{
      cx=DriverManager.getConnection(url, usr, pswd);
      String  sql="SELECT * FROM CHASIS";

        psd=cx.prepareStatement(sql);
        stt=psd.executeQuery();
        jTable2.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(stt));


    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex.getMessage(),"Renault Dacia ERRCHIDIA",0);

    }

}
```

// here you can see my new actionPerformed is inside the old one

```
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        
 else if(jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().equals("par position"))
 {
        try{

            cx=DriverManager.getConnection(url, usr, pswd);
            String  sql="SELECT * FROM CHASIS where position=?" ;
            psd=cx.prepareStatement(sql);
            psd.setString(1,jTextField5.getText());
            stt=psd.executeQuery();
            jTable2.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(stt));


        }catch(SQLException ex)
        {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex.getMessage(),"Renault Dacia ERRCHIDIA",0); }
    }
 else if(jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().equals("par marque"))
    {
        try{

            cx=DriverManager.getConnection(url, usr, pswd);
            String  sql="SELECT * FROM CHASIS where marque=?" ;
            psd=cx.prepareStatement(sql);
            psd.setString(1,jTextField5.getText());
            stt=psd.executeQuery();
            jTable2.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(stt));


        }catch(SQLException ex)
        {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex.getMessage(),"Renault Dacia ERRCHIDIA",0); }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh my. Did anybody ever tell you that **duplicating** code is the root of all evil in programming?!

Compare those to try blocks for example. The only difference there is the string you are using for your SQL statement. Anything else is ... all the same. You **never ever** do that. Instead, you write a helper method that knows **nothing** about UI elements (maybe except the model to update).

In other words: you could create a utility class which does the DB work for you; and your action listeners simply call the corresponding methods, providing the required parameters.

You know, that would also enable you to **test** your code separately. Whereas, in your approach, your stuffing all things together into one big monolith; which is almost impossible to test. And believe me: if this is a "real world" project, then you are about to create something that is absolutely not maintainable and will be continuous source of problems for you. The idea is that you create **layers** in your product; one for the UI, one for the "business logic"; others for "infrastructure" (like dealing with databases).

Seriously: you might want to study things like "clean code", or "how to do  good OO designs" before committing more such code crimes.